Reminder to Add Pics to Questions
Would it be worth it (if it's possible) to add a note to the "Ask Question" page suggesting people to provide pics?  Obviously, you can lead a horse to water but you can't make him drink, but having a suggestion/reminder there might help.

And properly size the photos (or has Stack Exchange fixed the issue with huge photos?) and include captions for the visually impaired.  So many people leave out the last item, likely simply because they don't know that some of our community members use screen readers.

On the other hand, there are plenty of times that pictures aren't all that important. Looking through the first page of questions at this very moment:

Have pictures: 28
Do not have pictures but would be helpful to have pictures: 11
Do not have pictures and pictures would probably not make much (if any) difference: 11

Of course, some of those 28 (not sure how many) are posts where the pictures were not included originally and were added later. And some of those were probably posts where OP would have included pictures originally but didn't because they didn't know how.
Which makes me think that as useful, or perhaps more useful, than simply "include pictures" would be "To add pictures, click on..." etc.

It could help. Maybe a good place is at the "Body" heading instructions:

Include all the information someone would need to answer your question.

However, considering the number of duplicate-like questions that come along, it seems many folks don't read the page well, considering there's an auto-search that tries to help them find the duplicates.
It would be interesting to see if more pictures get added?

Maybe a gatekeeper step?  Before allowing a question without a photo to be posted, another step that says "photos can help us provide you better answers—are you sure you don't want to include photos with your question?"
